# Why it is faster to return a tuple than multiple values in Python?

Tags: python, performance, tuples, return-value, benchmarking

I did a small test:

```
In [12]: def test1():
    ...:     return 1,2,3
    ...: 

In [13]: def test2():
    ...:     return (1,2,3)
    ...: 

In [14]: %timeit a,b,c = test1()
```

The slowest run took 66.88 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 92.7 ns per loop

```
In [15]: %timeit a,b,c = test2()
```

The slowest run took 74.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 80.1 ns per loop

**Returning a tuple is about 15% faster than returning multiple values. Why is it so?**

Comment: `test1` and `test2` are equivalent in terms of bytecode

Comment: @vaultah: so 1,2,3 is also a tuple?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes it is.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre in this case, yes.

Comment: The commas make a tuple, not the parenthesis.

Comment: There is no such a thing as "returning multiple values" in pyhon. both of your functions return a tuple and do exactly the same thing.  Profiling operations that complete in nanoseconds will *always* end up in noisy results so seeing a +/-15% in successive runs isn't abnormal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `test1` and `test2` results in same bytecode, so they have to perform in same speed. Your measurement conditions wasn't consistent (e.g. CPU load was increased for test2, due to additional background processes).

```
>>> import dis
>>> def test1():
...     return 1,2,3
...
>>> def test2():
...     return (1,2,3)
...
>>> dis.dis(test1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 2, 3))
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(test2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 2, 3))
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Comment: Did you re-run the test to verify?

Comment: @ReutSharabani yes, and results on my machine is super noisy. I get runs where test1 execution time is about test2 execution time, runs where test1 is longer than test2, runs where test2 is longer than test1. It's kind of expected where you have anything running in background and try to profile something that's super quick to execute.

Comment: ok, cause my runs were also inconsistent but don't have an environment to test in thats not loaded at the moment.

Comment: @ReutSharabani The syntax for creating tuples are the *commas*, the parenthesis are optional. So writing `x = 1,2,3` creates the tuple `(1,2,3)` **exactly** in the same way as writing `x = (1,2,3)`. The only difference occurs during parsing, but as shown in this answer the interpreter does **exactly** the same things in both cases. Now, given that the operations you are profiling are so fast it's expected that you'll see big difference during different runs. Try to run the test for `test1` multiple times and you'll see the timings wander off quite a bit.